# Custom DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer is not used when errors occurs during invalid message processing

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am trying to customize DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer but it seems that my customizations are ignored. Eg. When I am trying to set custom destinationResolver still default is used when wrong message is processed (DeserializationException occurs). Here is my configuration:

```
    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        var listenerFactory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object>();
        listenerFactory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        listenerFactory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.RECORD);
        DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer recoverer = new DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer(kafkaTemplate(), (r, e) -> {
            log.error("Custom error resolving {}", e);
            return null;
        });
        recoverer.setFailIfSendResultIsError(false);
        listenerFactory.setCommonErrorHandler(
                new DefaultErrorHandler(recoverer));
        return listenerFactory;

    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, Object> consumerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(
                kafkaConsumerProps,
                StringDeserializer::new,
                () -> new ErrorHandlingDeserializer<>(new KafkaAvroDeserializer()),
                true
        );
    }

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, Object> producerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(
                kafkaProducerProps,
                StringSerializer::new,
                KafkaAvroSerializer::new,
                true
        );
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, Object> kafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
    }

    @Bean
    public RetryTopicConfiguration retryTopicConfiguration(KafkaTemplate<String, Object> template,
                                                           ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> kafkaListenerContainerFactory) {
        return RetryTopicConfigurationBuilder
                .newInstance()
                .fixedBackOff(2000)
                .maxAttempts(3)
                .dltHandlerMethod("deadLetterHandler", "handle")
                .dltSuffix("-test-dlt")
                .retryTopicSuffix("-test-retry")
                .doNotRetryOnDltFailure()
                .listenerFactory(kafkaListenerContainerFactory)
                .create(template);
    }
```

I've checked that listener factory with default DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer is created and used here:

```
create:177, DeadLetterPublishingRecovererFactory (org.springframework.kafka.retrytopic)
decorate:239, ListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer$RetryTopicListenerContainerFactoryDecorator (org.springframework.kafka.retrytopic)
createListenerContainer:226, ListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer$RetryTopicListenerContainerFactoryDecorator (org.springframework.kafka.retrytopic)
createListenerContainer:207, ListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer$RetryTopicListenerContainerFactoryDecorator (org.springframework.kafka.retrytopic)
```

even if I specified it with   .listenerFactory(kafkaListenerContainerFactory) on RetryTopicConfiguration  bean

How can I improve my configuration to make custom DeadLetterPublishingRecovererFactory working?

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do; please explain your use case in more detailt.

Comment: I want to handle DeserializationException in DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer custom destinationResolver in order to avoid produce bad message to DLT. In project we agreed to use DLT topic only for exceptions that are not connected with deserialization but we want to have some control of it and eg. produce custom log/pass information about exception to some method without breaking retry/DLT flow for other exceptions

Answer (score 0):

Just setting a custom DLPR with the resolver there won't work.

You need to subclass `RetryTopicConfigurationSupport` [https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#retry-topic-global-settings`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#retry-topic-global-settings%60) and override `createComponentFactory()` to return a custom `RetryTopicComponentFactory` which returns a custom `DeadLetterPublishingRecovererFactory`.

However, you can't just replace the default resolver; you will need to delegate to the default one for all other exception types.

**EDIT**

It was a bit more involved than I thought; here is an example:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class So77058404Application extends RetryTopicConfigurationSupport {

    private static final String DESER_EX_TOPIC = "deser.ex.topic";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So77058404Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected RetryTopicComponentFactory createComponentFactory() {

        AtomicReference<DestinationTopic.Properties> dltProps = new AtomicReference<>();

        class CustomRetryTopicNamesProviderFactory implements RetryTopicNamesProviderFactory {

            @Override
            public RetryTopicNamesProvider createRetryTopicNamesProvider(
                    DestinationTopic.Properties properties) {

                if (properties.isDltTopic()) {
                    dltProps.set(properties);
                }
                return new SuffixingRetryTopicNamesProvider(properties);
            }
        }

        return new RetryTopicComponentFactory() {

            @Override
            public RetryTopicNamesProviderFactory retryTopicNamesProviderFactory() {
                return new CustomRetryTopicNamesProviderFactory();
            }

            @Override
            public DeadLetterPublishingRecovererFactory deadLetterPublishingRecovererFactory(
                    DestinationTopicResolver destinationTopicResolver) {

                return super.deadLetterPublishingRecovererFactory(new DestinationTopicResolver() {

                    @Override
                    public DestinationTopic getNextDestinationTopicFor(String mainListenerId, String topicName) {
                        return destinationTopicResolver.getNextDestinationTopicFor(mainListenerId, topicName);
                    }

                    @Override
                    @Nullable
                    public DestinationTopic getDltFor(String mainListenerId, String topicName) {
                        return destinationTopicResolver.getDltFor(mainListenerId, topicName);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public DestinationTopic getDestinationTopicByName(String mainListenerId, String topicName) {
                        if (topicName.equals(DESER_EX_TOPIC)) {
                            return new DestinationTopic(DESER_EX_TOPIC, dltProps.get());
                        }
                        return destinationTopicResolver.getDestinationTopicByName(mainListenerId, topicName);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void addDestinationTopics(String mainListenerId, List<DestinationTopic> destinationTopics) {
                        destinationTopicResolver.addDestinationTopics(mainListenerId, destinationTopics);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public DestinationTopic resolveDestinationTopic(String mainListenerId, String topic,
                            Integer attempt, Exception ex, long originalTimestamp) {

                        if (ex.getCause() instanceof DeserializationException) {
                            return new DestinationTopic(DESER_EX_TOPIC, dltProps.get());
                        }
                        return destinationTopicResolver.resolveDestinationTopic(mainListenerId, topic, attempt, ex,
                                originalTimestamp);
                    }

                });

            }

        };
    }

    @Bean
    NewTopic topic() {
        return TopicBuilder.name(DESER_EX_TOPIC).partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }

    @Bean
    ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaTemplate<String, String> template, DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<Object, Object> pf) {
        pf.setValueSerializer(new DelegatingByTypeSerializer(Map.of(
                byte[].class, new ByteArraySerializer(),
                String.class, new StringSerializer())));
        return args -> {
            template.send("so77058404", "ok1");
            template.send("so77058404", "###junk###");
            template.send("so77058404", "ok2");
        };
    }

}

@Component
class Listener {

    @KafkaListener(id = "so77058404", topics = "so77058404")
    @RetryableTopic
    void listen(String in, @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC) String topic) {
        System.out.println(in + " from " + topic);
        throw new RuntimeException("test");
    }

    @DltHandler
    void handle(String in, @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC) String topic) {
        System.out.println(in + " from " + topic);
    }

}
```

```java
public class BadDeserializer implements Deserializer<Object> {

    @Override
    public Object deserialize(String topic, byte[] data) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object deserialize(String topic, Headers headers, byte[] data) {
        if (data[0] == 0x23) {
            throw new RuntimeException("test");
        }
        return new String(data);
    }

}
```

```
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.deserializer.value.delegate.class=com.example.demo.BadDeserializer
```

The `okN` messages go through the retry process (ending up in the default DLT); the `###JUNK###` message goes straight to the custom DLT.

Comment: If I can not replace default resolver(so I can not replace behavior of DLPR for eg. DeserializationException(?)) do you have any suggestions how to resolve my issue? I can see that eg. I can set in ErrorHandlingDeserializer  custom method failedDeserializationFunction which seems to be what I want but in callback parameters there are no info about eg. current offset to make acknowledge that message was processed (without it I end up with infinity loop)

Comment: You just need to call the default resolver for exception types other than `DeserializationException`s - the default resolver is passed into the component factory's `deadLetterPublishingRecovererFactory()` method.

Comment: It was a bit more involved than I thought it would be (or should be); I added an example. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/2800